# Percentages of subtotal in a report

Tags: visual-studio-2008, report-designer

I am using Report Designer in VS 2008. Is there a way to display the percentages of a subtotal in a crosstab report?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want something that looks like this:

```
ITEM_ID  |  AMOUNT  |  % OF TOTAL
-----------------------------------
    1    |    20    |     10%
    2    |    30    |     15%
    3    |    40    |     20%
    4    |    50    |     25%
    5    |    60    |     30%
```

The value of your Amount column, by default, should contain an expression like:
**`=Fields!Amount.Value`**

So the value of a percentage column would contain the expression:
**`=(Fields!Amount.Value / Sum(Fields!Amount.Value) * 100) & "%"`**